# how to add stores and views programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, stores, install-script

can I use install scripts to configure multiple stores and views?

Can I find any examples?
thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To add a store use the code below:

```
//#addWebsite
/** @var $website Mage_Core_Model_Website */
$website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
$website->setCode('<your_website_code_here>')
    ->setName('<your_website_name>')
    ->save();

//#addStoreGroup
/** @var $storeGroup Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
$storeGroup = Mage::getModel('core/store_group');
$storeGroup->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
    ->setName('<your_store_name>')
    ->setRootCategoryId('<needed_root_category_id>')
    ->save();

//#addStore
/** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
$store->setCode('<your_store_view_code_here>')
    ->setWebsiteId($storeGroup->getWebsiteId())
    ->setGroupId($storeGroup->getId())
    ->setName('<your_store_view_name>')
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->save();
```

Thanks to [Zyava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320733/zyava) for providing this answer

Comment: Sorry, is that an install or data script? thanks